# Magento 2.3 — Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3, form-key

Getting **Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page** error not able to do any action after upgrade of **Magento 2.2.5 to Magento 2.3**.

Comment: Check this out 
https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-invalid-form-key/

Comment: Are you on local server ? like xampp ?

Comment: Yes, im using xampp for local

Comment: What's your base Url ? If its localhost/your-project-name than you can give a try to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 

Run setup:upgrade It should solve your issue.

Comment: i don't think so its a server issue, because till now i'm using magento 2.2.5 there is no issues when i upgraded to 2.3 then only this issue came.

Comment: i am also getting the same issue with cardstream payment gateway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I got the solution

I have a custom payment method that uses the cc-form to take credit card payments with and without 3dsecure. After placing order with 3dsecure, I am re-directing to 3dsecure page as normal, but on returning from 3dsecure, I am re-directed to the home page with "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page why because in Magento 2.3 core payment methods are using CsrfAwareActionInterface for each controller."

So now i have implemented same thing in my custom payment method as below

```
use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CustomPaymentResponse extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements CsrfAwareActionInterface

/** 
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function createCsrfValidationException(
    RequestInterface $request 
): ?InvalidRequestException {
    return null;
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
{
    return true;
}
```

**Note :** you can get reference from core module. Here is the core file path **vendor\magento\module-authorizenet\Controller\Directpost\Payment\BackendResponse.php**.

Comment: I have tried this but this is not working with me . I used a custom payment method (paytab) and the call back url from the payment method is giving me a 302 found and redirects to home page with the same message.

Comment: Thanks @bangaram you have saved our time.

Comment: validateForCsrf is there for security reasons! you must not always return true!

Comment: Its works! Thanks for your post!

Answer (score 2):

```
    use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

    class CustomPaymentResponse extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements CsrfAwareActionInterface

    /** 
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function createCsrfValidationException(
        RequestInterface $request 
    ): ?InvalidRequestException {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
    {
        return true;
    }
   /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
   public function execute()
    {
    //your response check
    }
```

Your response controller should be like this, then  only form key issue will fix.

Referrence: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19712